# Relation of Smalltalk VM and image?

Tags: smalltalk

I was thinking wrong. I thought Smalltalk is monolithic stuff, but recently I realized Smalltalk is separated into VM and image. And in this case, I can call the VM is essential part and image is just collection of applications. Language syntax is just helper to make the image code.

And this made me to have some questions.

1. It seems possible to run an *image* on any Smalltalk VM. Is this true? For example, can I run Seaside from any Smalltalk VM?
2. It seems all Smalltalk VMs should be fully compatible. At least in set of features and executing source codes. Is this true?
3. Is it possible to construct my own *image* on bare-bone VM? It wouldn't be practical, but should be nice for learning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll try to answer your questions (thou surely other Smalltalkers here will provide more details):

> 1. This seems it's possible running image on any Smalltalk VM. Is this possible? For example, can I run Seaside from any Smalltalk VM?

Smalltalk has many dialects, which means that there are many combinations of Image+Vm. Some of them are [Pharo](http://www.pharo-project.org/), [Squeak](http://www.squeak.org/), [VisualWorks](http://www.cincomsmalltalk.com/main/), [Dolphin](http://www.object-arts.com/), [GNU Smalltalk](http://smalltalk.gnu.org/), [Amber](http://amber-lang.net/), [Gemstone](http://www.gemstone.com/products/gemstone) (and I'm surely missing some more). However, each image runs with its specific VM, since things like primitives or memory management are defined by each VM. As a matter of fact, depending on the Smalltalk flavor, images my be incompatible even between major releases.

Having said that, Seaside is a particular web framework, which has been ported to different Smalltalk flavors. So you can write a Seaside-based application in one St (e.g. Pharo) and export the code en import it in another St (e.g. Gemstone).

> This seems all Smalltalk VMs should be fully compatible. At least in
>   set of features and executing source codes. Is this true?

Yes, the basic **conceptual** idea is the same in most Smalltalks. If you want to be flavor-compatible you should try to stick to the ANSI Smalltalk specs, and you will be able (with some headaches :)) to move code across dialects. Note however that this is not a usual thing, since most of the time you will be working with a specific one (maybe the Squeak/Pharo <=> Gemstone combination is the most common and AFAIK it works quite good).

> Is it possible to construct my own image on bare-bone VM? It wouldn't
>   be practical, but should be nice for learning.

As I said before, there are many things inside an image that you should take care of in order to do that. So, technically, yes you can, practically, its hard. There were a series of [blog posts](http://marianopeck.wordpress.com/tag/vm/) by Mariano titled "Journey through the Virtual Machine” which you can find interesting. Also, AFAIK Tim Budd created [Little Smalltalk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Smalltalk) as a learning source (I need to find the quote :( ). Anyway, there are countless example of people that build their own Smalltalk VM in order to learn how they work. It is a hard work, but you will definitely learn a lot (I know you asked to build an image, but it may be useful to know that you can also build a VM). Oh, you may also be interested in [this link](http://astares.blogspot.com.ar/2011/03/birth-of-smalltalk-image.html).

HTH

Comment: Oh it's sad that building an image from scratch is hard as much as building VM. Is it because each base image should access some hard-core VM internals? If so, it maybe be easier making my own VM :)

Comment: Its more the other way around; the VM expects some specific things about the image. Also you should know how specifics (e.g the VM bytecodes) in order to create a Smalltalk compiler inside the image (remember that almost everything is solved inside the image, so even the compiler is an object that lives in it). That is why I think that it would be better for you to build a VM instead of an image. However, please take a look at [Hazelnut](http://rmod.lille.inria.fr/web/pier/software/Seed), I think you will find it very interesting.

Comment: Oh yes, the last links(PharoKernel and Hazenut) are exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: It seems Smalltalk VM structure is very similar to Objective-C runtime  which is influenced from Smalltalk :)

Answer (score 5):

To answer to question 3), about image creation, another POV is based on biological metaphor.

Creating an image from scratch is very difficult, like building a living cell from scratch is very difficult: there are a lot of interactions to take into account (creationists would say you must be a sort of god to do that).

However, cloning an image is a very easy operation, as cloning a cell (you just let it clone itself). It's so easy that we usually just clone - e.g. Squeak and Pharo images are more than several decade old now - see funny discussion *About a object life* on squeak-dev mailing list http://forum.world.st/About-a-object-life-td4653839.html .

Note that gnu-Smalltalk has all the tools to assemble an image from scratch, and it is in Pharo plans to re-create such tools.

Last point, Squeak cares about backward compatibility and recent interpreter VM still provides necessary interface to run an image frozen a decade ago.

Comment: I like playing a god-game. I am a real crazy god-game-holic :)

Comment: I really like the explanations in the mailing list link about the age of objects in a Smalltalk image..

Answer (score 3):

Smallatalk VM's from different vendors are generally not compatible, and image saved with one VM can not be loaded into another one, at least not directly. Exception is that Squeak and Pharo images share (or most of the time) same VM interface.

Seaside programs can (and do) get transported between images in differenr VM's as source packages.

It is possible to construct your image from the scratch, though good understanding of the VM would be needed. You may find [Spoon](http://www.netjam.org/spoon/) system interesting.

Comment: Can I treat *Spoon* is something like PharoKernel and Hazelnut?

Comment: Yes, pretty much. It holds the record so far for smallest Smalltalk image ever - _padded_ to 1337 bytes!

Answer (score 1):

VM is a layer between Smalltalk byte code and system. So the main idea is when you execute 4 + 5 a VM *primitive* is called that executes corresponding machine codes to sum that stuff as out CPU does not know what is "an object". So you can't run anything on anything. This is why NBCog is present. Native Boost needs some special primitives that are not implemented in Cog vm, so it will work only on NBCog. I don't understand your 3rd question. VM takes smalltalk byte-code and outputs machine code. What is a bare-bone VM?

Comment: I was wanted to run VM without image. Just Smalltalk environment with really core minimal objects. (or no objects) which I can construct everything from scratch. Currently, SqueakVM doesn't run without an image, and I can get only all-in-one image...

Comment: Maybe Spoon system mentioned in my answer will be of interest to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't run a Smalltalk vm without an image. It's an utterly meaningless idea -  the entire point of the vm is to run the image. It would be like running a picture viewer without a picture.

Comment: This does not appear to address any part of the question.

Comment: Oh? You don't understand the idea of explaining the big picture instead of nitpicking? The original post suggested a complete lack of knowledge about the subject; various people have tried to help. I pointed out that the op was essentially a category error. Sometimes that's the only meaningful answer.

Comment: Oh, and to directly answer eonil, a Smalltalk environment with really core minimal objects *is* an image.